# Uber developer API support contact

Tags: uber-api

I have applied for uber api but its been two weeks and I haven't heard anything from them. Does anybody know how to contact uber developer support. Because i contacted their normal support and they seems unaware too. They send me a link which on takes me to a uber support page but that page doesn't have any answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how to contact Uber developer support and not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Uber API contact page: https://developer.uber.com/support

The reason you are being downvoted is because your question is not appropriate for StackOverflow as it is not a technical / programming question. In this case reaching out to Uber would be more appropriate (from that link options that would make sense would be posting on their google group forum or DM'ing on Twitter.)

If by "applying for Uber API" you are referring to Driver API (https://developer.uber.com/products/drivers), that access is currently limited and if you have not heard back in two weeks that means you likely were not accepted at this time.

Hope that helps.